# How can I flat a list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flatten

I have a dict which contain a list `product` which will contain only one dict :

```
dic = {
    "thickness": 90.0,
    "mass_surf": 37.8,
    "res_therm": 0.75,
    "codename": "codename1",
    "category": "category1",
    "sub_categories": [
        "sub_categories1"
    ],
    "secondary_targets": [
        "secondary_targets1",
        "secondary_targets2",
        "secondary_targets3"
    ],
    "product": [
        {
            "codename": "codename1",
            "purpose": "purpose1",
            "category": "category1",
            "material": "material1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to flat the `product` list of dict to obtain this:

```
dic = {
    "thickness": 90.0,
    "mass_surf": 37.8,
    "res_therm": 0.75,
    "codename": "codename1",
    "category": "category1",
    "sub_categories": [
        "sub_categories1"
    ],
    "secondary_targets": [
        "secondary_targets1",
        "secondary_targets2",
        "secondary_targets3"
    ],
    "product.codename": "codename1",
    "product.purpose": "purpose 1",
    "product.purpose": "purpose1",
    "product.category": "category1",
    "product.material": "material1"
}
```

How can I do this?

**`product` list will always contains only one item**

Comment: What if the product list has more than one entry?

Comment: don't name dictionaries `dict`, this is a python builtin

Comment: The product list will always have only one product, indeed it's a bit confusing but the field `product` is a list due to the return of a Mongo query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flat a list of containing only one dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70347192/flat-a-list-of-containing-only-one-dict)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only one item in the sublist, you could use the following dictionary comprehension:

```
out = {'.'.join([k1,k2]) if k2 else k1: v2
       for k1,v1 in d.items()
       for k2,v2 in (v1[0] if isinstance(v1, list) else {None: v1}).items()
       }
```

output:

```
{'product.codename': 'codename1',
 'product.name': 'name1',
 'product.category': 'category1',
 'message': 'message1'}
```

*NB. If you can have more than one item in the list, **please clarify how to handle them.***

Comment: Thank you @mozway, I tried it and it works perfectly!
However I want to design it to flat only the `product` field. I edit my question to add more details and information about my request